# How to adjust the height of each cell in the gridview?

Tags: android, height, cell, android-gridview

I have gridview containing text view and an image view.I tried to adjust the height of the layout and content inside the layout ie textview and imageview,but no use.How to adjust the the height of a cell in an gridview.

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridviewevents"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:columnWidth="40dp"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:numColumns="7"
     />
```

The following xml contains the elements inside each cell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linlay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"

android:layout_height="35dp"
android:background="@drawable/calendar_cell"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:textColor="#0000D7"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/date_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/event"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **1** Your LinearLayout is left open. **2** You don't need it - Simply use the TextView to contain the image as a compound drawable (1 Layout and 1 View saved). For reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableTop

Comment: You can not do this you must make minimum height for You TextView and ImageView in following xml layout

Comment: @hema18 i updated my code but no use

Comment: Make minimum height for textview and imageview to be a maximum value possible to happen. The highest image you have is 50 db so you must to set minimum height of your imageView to 50 db, same thing for textView with maximum lines possible to happen

Comment: @DerGolem i cant get rid of that imageview...it is important..

Comment: You can put it **inside** the TextView - being no more a separate View.

Comment: @DerGolem dint understand...wht if i use two views??

Comment: It's a **waste**. Using a single TextView is **better for performances**.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

ensures that the Height from the ImageView and TextView wil not be bigger or smaller then the height of its content within it (so the text or image on te views).

There are also

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
WRAP_CONTENT, which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding).

If you use FILL_PARENT make sure u use also

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

If every element or cell has weight "1", all elements will have the same size. E.g. if the weight of ImageView is "2" and the TextView is "1", then ImageView will be twice as big.

More information on 
[the Android-site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)